# How to return the number of elements of a vector variable in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have declared a vector.

Then I ask user to enter the name of an author, then I add the name of the author to the collection:

```
vector<string> AuthorsCollection;
.
.
AuthorsCollection.pushback(UserInput);
```

Everything works well, but when I get the size of vector:

```
AuthorsCollection.size()
```

It returns the number of characters, while I have just added one input as string. I need to get the number of elements of a vector, which in my case must be one and not number of characters of the inserted string.

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    string AuthorNameByUser;

    SimpleClass SC;
    SecondClass SecondClass;
    SC.SetAuthorName("Jack London");

    cout << "This is our selected Author: " << SC.AuthorName << endl;

    cout << "Number of sold works: " << SC.GetAuthorNumOfSoldWorks() << " works." << endl;

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Please type the name of your favorite author: ";

    getline(cin, AuthorNameByUser);

    /*while (AuthorNameByUser != "final")
    {
        getline(cin, AuthorNameByUser);
    }*/

    SecondClass.AddAuthor(AuthorNameByUser);

    vector<string> AuthorsCollection = SecondClass.GetAuthors();

    int AuthorsQuantity = AuthorNameByUser.size();

    cout << "Thank for your particpiation. You have entered \"" << AuthorsCollection[0] << "\"" << endl;

    cout << endl << AuthorsQuantity << endl;
}
```

Comment: `AuthorsCollection.size()` gives you the number of elements.

Comment: When I say it returns the number of character, then it returns the number of characters. It does not return the number of elements, though generically I might have gone wrong in the code.

Comment: Post some code that reproduces the "problem". Because `std::vector::size()` returns the number of elements.

Comment: `size` returns number of element..see here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/

Comment: Posted code does not show the error. Hence downvoted. [Post a Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why don't you provide some more detail in your example code - include some sample input strings, and then show the output that you actually get from calling size() based on those inputs?

Comment: @MostafaTalebi no, it does not: http://ideone.com/28X4LX

Comment: You use a string and get it's size... you don't even use vector... is it a troll thread?

Comment: what are you talking about? It is a string added to a vector whose base-data-type is string

Comment: `string AuthorNameByUser;` -> `int AuthorsQuantity = AuthorNameByUser.size();`
Where is your vector?

Answer (score 2):

> How to return the number of elements of a vector variable in C++

With the `std::vector::size()` member function:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> v;
  v.push_back("Hello, World!");
  std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
  v.push_back("foo bar baz");
  std::cout << v.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

**Edit**:

The reason for your confusion is that you are printing out the size of a `string`, not a `vector<string>`:

```
string AuthorNameByUser;
....
int AuthorsQuantity = AuthorNameByUser.size();
....
cout << endl << AuthorsQuantity << endl;
```

Comment: Downvoter, what is the problem with this answer? Is there a better and more idiomatic way to get the number of elements in a vector?

Comment: i think he edited his code and is now downvoting on the basis of new code

Comment: @rock321987 Could be. In any case, I added an explanation for OP's confusion, in case it wasn't blindingly obvious.

Comment: +1 for that..i think it should be clear to him by now

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main(void)
{
    std::string UserInput;
    std::vector<std::string> AuthorsCollection;

    for (int i = 0;;i++) {
        std::cin >> UserInput;
        AuthorsCollection.push_back(UserInput);
        std::cout << AuthorsCollection.size() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want anyone on the forum to help you, you have to provide more information. Make sure you do that next time, please. 
I don't know if this is what you are trying to do -- I'm just guessing here so why don't you try something like?

```
//This works for me:

// preprocessor includes
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// simplify calls to the standard library
using namespace std;

// class definition & implementation
class second_class
{
public:
    void add_author( string name )
    {
        authors.push_back( name );
    }

    /**
     * This function returns a copy of the authors member variable.
     */
    vector<string> get_authors() const
    {
        return authors;
    }

private:
    vector<string> authors;
};

/**
 * Program execution begins here.
 * Ignores command line arguments.
 * @return An integer representing success, or failure.
 */
int main( int argc, const char * argv[] )
{
    string author_name;                // hold authors names
    second_class second_class;         // instance of a second_class
    vector<string> authors_collection; //

    cout << "Please type the name of your favorite author: ";
    getline( cin, author_name );

    second_class.add_author( author_name );

    authors_collection = second_class.get_authors();

    cout << "Thank for your particpiation. You have entered \""
         << authors_collection[0] << "\""
         << endl;

    cout << endl << authors_collection.size() << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```